# React: "Удаление компонента из массива компонентов"

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет.

Parent компонент хранит стейт и метод с SetState который должен отрендерить заново компоненты, оба далее предаются к Child и Subchild's через props.

Subchild содержит кнопку которая удаляет самого себя вызывает метод SetState у Parent.

Вопрос: почему при клике на кнопку к Subchild приходят props без элемента который я удалил, но появляется ошибка, удалённый элемент пытается отрендерится но не находит данных в props.
По идее в props.items.map его ведь не должно быть.

```
<Parent>
    <Child>
        props.items.map(function (product, index) {
           return ( <Subchild key={index} props={props} method={method}/> )
           }
    <Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: извините, вопрос очень увлекательный, но ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас в `Parent` хранится state со списком `Child` компонентов.
2. `Parent` рендерит `Сhild` компоненты.
3. `Child` рендерит `Subchild` компоненты.
4. `Subchild` рендерит кнопку, клик по которой удаляет `Subchild`

В вашем случае, встретив удаленный элемент, map вернет конструкцию вида `<Subchild key={undefined} props={undefined} method={undefined}/>` (или что-то подобное, в зависимости от того, как вы удаляете `Subchild`. Т.к. в текущем виде `Child` знает, что если он рендерит себя, то он обязан отрендерить и Subchild, даже если он его не найдет в стейте.
Чтобы подобное поведение исключить надо добавить еще 1 проверку.

```
props.items.map(function (product, index) {
    if (isDeleted) //Ваше условие, по которому можно понять, что Subchild удален и его не надо рендерить.
         return ( <Subchild key={index} props={props} method={method}/> )
}
```